# Ubuntu 16.04 Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors

Tags: hdmi, display-resolution, xrandr

Good afternoon,

system is Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X220 in a docking station, which outputs sound via DP and video via VGA cable.

Since sometimes VGA output or DP (in xrandr HDMI-2) sound is not connected there is a startup-script:

```
if xrandr | grep -i "VGA-1 connected"; then 
xrandr --newmode "720p" 74.48 1280 1336 1472 1664 720 721 724 746 -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "720p"
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode "720p"
xrandr --output VGA-1 --primary
if xrandr | grep -i "HDMI-2 connected"; then
    xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "720p"
    xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off
    xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode "720p"
    xrandr --output HDMI-2 --same-as VGA-1
fi
elif xrandr | grep -i "HDMI-2 connected"; then          
xrandr --newmode "720p" 74.48 1280 1336 1472 1664 720 721 724 746 -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "720p"
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode "1280x720"
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode "720p" --same-as LVDS-1
else
echo "kein Beamer an"
fi
```

works fine :), but still having the error message "Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors" each startup.

Some advise was checking monitors.xml

```
cat $HOME/.config/monitors.xml
```

but it looks perfect:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>yes</clone>
      <output name="LVDS-1">
          <vendor>LGD</vendor>
          <product>0x02d8</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
      </output>
      <output name="VGA-1">
          <vendor>???</vendor>
          <product>0x0000</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1280</width>
          <height>720</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-1">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-1">
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-2">
          <vendor>MEI</vendor>
          <product>0xd043</product>
          <serial>0x15121053</serial>
          <width>1280</width>
          <height>720</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-3">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-2">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-3">
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

So now I am posting...

Thanks in advance, best regards, Joachim

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

what helped was:

```
rm  ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

No troubles yet.

On the long term I am thinking about creating a shutdown script executing above code...